# Create ISO from Elementary OS

Tags: iso

I am not yet ready to switch definitely to Juno, as several apps needed for my work environment are still missing, but nevertheless, i wanted to create an *.iso of my current E. Juno Os. So i did with my home folder (example code):

```
mkisofs -o destination-filename.iso /home/username
```

But…the point is i wanted to create an iso from my whole operating system.
The point is to safe my applications and its documents. How to do that?

I looked around for awhile and did not find anything useful to backup my OS. After installing systemback from "https://code.launchpad.net/~nemh"
all i got was a waring that pops up all times when i open the "AppCenter":

(i translate from German)

```
Update download failed

This might happen for external installed software-repositories or caused by a corrupt sources.list file
```

I would be happy if you could help me also with this issue, as the original problem connects both problems…

Answer (score 1):

This might not sound as a direct answer to how to create ISO, but still.
As far as I understand, you need ISO to create a backup of your current system. If so, you could try making a more reliable system backup via backup software such as [Timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift) instead, then write backup folder to removable media/DVD/remote disk and use it later if need be.